# Как сделать что-бы при перетаскивании элемента списка не отрисовывалать корзина и фон?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть список recyclerView. Элементы которого можно удалять свайпом влево. Также их можно перетаскивать и менять местами. В функции onChildDraw есть код, который внутри элемента списка рисует значек корзины и фон удаления. Как сделать что-бы во время перетаскивания элемента списка корзина и фон не отрисовывались?
Фрагмент кода с функцией onChildDraw:

```
override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
                    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                    val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
                    val itemHeight = itemView.height
                    val isCancelled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive
                    if (isCancelled) {
                        //clearCanvas(c, itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
                        c.drawRect(itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat(), Paint())
                        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                        return
                    }
                    val deleteDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp);
                    val intrinsicWidth = deleteDrawable!!.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    val intrinsicHeight = deleteDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    val mBackground = ColorDrawable()
                    mBackground.color = Color.parseColor("#D81B60")//"#b80f0a")
                    mBackground.setBounds(itemView.right + (dX*1/columnsCount).toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
                    mBackground.draw(c)
                    val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
                    val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / (columnsCount * columnsCount)
                    val deleteIconLeft = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth
                    val deleteIconRight = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin
                    val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight
                    deleteDrawable.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
                    deleteDrawable.draw(c)
                    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                }
```

Comment: [Вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529652/9057721)